# How to read the text from shapes in word using Apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am able to read the text from paragraph and table from Apache POI but when the text inside the text box or in any shapes that Microsoft offered then I am not able to read such a text I tried the apache poi documentation and few more sites but didn't got the code or any implementation part.
If Apache poi can read such text i.e When text inside any shapes or text box.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the exact solution to your scenario , but following should get you going.

```
 if (cell instanceof CommonObjectDataSubRecord) {
    CommonObjectDataSubRecord obj= (CommonObjectDataSubRecord) sub;
    if (obj.getObjectType() == CommonObjectDataSubRecord.OBJECT_TYPE_TEXT) {
          // Check the  obj for the value of text box
    }
}
```

If this does not solve your issue , read about [CommonObjectDataSubRecord](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/record/CommonObjectDataSubRecord.html)

Comment: Sorry ,man.AFK for a while.You will have to look it up for yourself.